# Custom Button SOQL Error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I wrote a custom button to execute a javasacript query, but when trying to retreive the name field from the query results, I get an error.

> Error: 0 not defined

```
if( {!Not(ISNULL(Account.LocationId__c))}  && "  {!$UserRole.Name}"!=="Community Administration Officer" )
{
  var AccCheck1 = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Name FROM    sked__Location__c WHERE Id ='{!Account.LocationId__c}'"); 
  var Rec1 = AccCheck1.getArray("Rec1"); 
  var LocName=AccCheck1.Rec1[0].Name;    // here it gives error 0 not defined

  if(LocName=="community")
  alert('You Can not create record on Community Location.')
}
```

Comment: Suggest you base your query result handling on examples such as [Examples of Synchronous Calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm).

Comment: instead of this `AccCheck1.Rec1[0].Name` do this `Rec1[0].Name`

Comment: @Tushar Sharma, I tried 'Rec1[0].Name' , but it also give error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array is named "records", so it should be:

```
var Rec1 = AccCheck1.getArray("records");
var locName = Rec1[0].Name;
```

Note that JavaScript is case sensitive, and you need to make sure you're referencing the right variables. See [Examples of Synchronous Calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm) for more details.

Comment: I've tired this also but it gives "error cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: @Amol It's case sensitive; are you sure you used "Name" and not "name"?

Comment: yes i've uesd as mention in my code. like "var LocName=Rec1[0].Name;"

Comment: @Amol If you're following the directions in the code I linked, it'll work. You need to follow the examples *directly*. JavaScript is not nearly as forgiving as Apex Code.

Comment: as per syntax and my knowledge everything  is correct. i'm stuck in it why it gives error.

Comment: @Amol Your original code is not correct. Use "records" to get the array. You may also want to check some debug statements.